# re-ordering a pandas dataframe to match column elements in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to reorder one data frame to match the order of two columns in another data frame.

This approach works -- but surely someone can suggest a more efficient approach?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X_intent' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                   'Y_intent' :np.ravel([np.repeat(1,8),np.repeat(2,8), np.repeat(3,8)]),
                   'Values' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

p = pd.DataFrame( {'OrderX': [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], 'OrderY': np.ravel([np.repeat(1,8),np.repeat(2,8), np.repeat(3,8)])})

p['indx'] =  p.OrderX.astype(str)+' '+p.OrderY.astype(str)
df['indx'] =  df.X_intent.astype(str)+' '+df.Y_intent.astype(str)

res = list()
for i in p["indx"]:
    res.append(np.where(df['indx'] == i))

res = [np.asscalar(item[0]) for sublist in l for item in res]

df.iloc[res]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is possible use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), if all values in both `DataFrame` is possible use default `inner` join, `rename` is used for avoid duplication columns with same values:

```
c = {'OrderX':'X_intent','OrderY':'Y_intent'}
df = p.rename(columns=c).merge(df, on=['X_intent','Y_intent'])
print (df)

    X_intent  Y_intent  Values
0          8         1       8
1          7         1       7
2          6         1       6
3          5         1       5
4          4         1       4
5          3         1       3
6          2         1       2
7          1         1       1
8          8         2       8
9          7         2       7
10         6         2       6
11         5         2       5
12         4         2       4
13         3         2       3
14         2         2       2
15         1         2       1
16         8         3       8
17         7         3       7
18         6         3       6
19         5         3       5
20         4         3       4
21         3         3       3
22         2         3       2
23         1         3       1
```

---

```
df = p.merge(df, left_on=['OrderX','OrderY'], right_on=['X_intent','Y_intent'])
print (df)
    OrderX  OrderY  X_intent  Y_intent  Values
0        8       1         8         1       8
1        7       1         7         1       7
2        6       1         6         1       6
3        5       1         5         1       5
4        4       1         4         1       4
5        3       1         3         1       3
6        2       1         2         1       2
7        1       1         1         1       1
8        8       2         8         2       8
9        7       2         7         2       7
10       6       2         6         2       6
11       5       2         5         2       5
12       4       2         4         2       4
13       3       2         3         2       3
14       2       2         2         2       2
15       1       2         1         2       1
16       8       3         8         3       8
17       7       3         7         3       7
18       6       3         6         3       6
19       5       3         5         3       5
20       4       3         4         3       4
21       3       3         3         3       3
22       2       3         2         3       2
23       1       3         1         3       1
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks!